# Count the deleted files Shell script

Tags: shell

Can you tell me how can you count the files with the extension ".txt" you delete from a folder? Shell script in Unix

Thank you for your answer :)

I tried to delete them this way :

deleted=0

while read line
do

```
if test -d "$line"
then

for i in "$line"/*
do


    if test -f "$i"
    then
    deleted=`ls -l $line |grep "*.o" | wc -l`
    echo "From: " $line " I deleted : " $deleted
    find . -type f -name "*.o" -exec rm -f {} \;

    else
    echo "Not file " $i                   
    fi

done

else
echo "NOT a directory!"
fi
```

done

Comment: More information would be helpful. Thank you too!

Comment: This question contains no information that will allow us to help you. What "shell"? What operating system? What have you tried so far? You need to [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14718516/edit) and provide much more detail (and show some effort to try and figure it out yourself first) if you want us to help you. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has some tips on writing questions in a way that will improve your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
LANG=C rm -v *.txt | grep -c "^removed "
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer - though not necessarily the right one:

```
files=*.txt
ls -1 "$files" | wc -l
rm "$files"
```

Ruth